# asp.net use .json as additional config file

Tags: asp.net, config

I have some configurable logic, but format is very dynamic, so I think best way how to write this is using .json format.

What is the best way to use this config similarly to Web.config? What I mean is:

- .json file is read to memory every time it changes. I do not want to read and deserialize it for every request.
- I also want some kind of global way to access this config (in memory). Maybe a static class?